# Folders with the same name in the same Location

Tags: windows-7

Here are the properties of just 2 with the same name :

[image]

The computer is 32 bit windows 7 professional SP1

I this when I tried to copy the parent folder to an external hardrive and 
was given the "folder of name xxx already exists at this destination etc".
As it transpires there are thousands of pairs of folders with the same names in the parent directory.
When you view the parent folder contents in windows explorer (sorted by name) it scrolls from A-Z and then A-Z again?
How is this possible?

Comment: Check the file system health by running the following command from an elevated command prompt: `chkdsk C: /r`

Comment: Yep, the directory is kind of hosed.  `chkdsk` might fix it (and is probably safer to try that several other "fixes").  Or you can try simply deleting one set (I'd try just one or two folders first, in case it ends up deleting both).

Comment: (How it got that way, I haven't a clue, but I've seen stranger things.)